# Anidar un ciclo for un número indefinido de veces hasta cumplir una condición

Tags: r, bucle-for, bucles

Lo que me gustaría hacer es **continuar con el proceso de los for un numero indefinido de veces, hasta que se cumpla alguno de los if**.

Pienso que se puede hacer con una función **recursiva**.

```
ruta <- function(desde, hasta) {
if(hasta==desde){return(hasta)}
else if(sonVecinos(desde,hasta)){return(c(desde,hasta))}
else{

  for (i in vecindad(desde)) {
    if (sonVecinos(i, hasta)) {
      return(c(desde, i, hasta))
    }

    for (j in vecindad(i)) {
      if (sonVecinos(j, hasta)) {
        return(c(desde, i, j, hasta))
      }

      for (k in vecindad(j)) {
        if (sonVecinos(k, hasta)) {
          return(c(desde, i, j, k, hasta))
        }

        for (l in vecindad(k)) {
          if (sonVecinos(l, hasta)) {
            return(c(desde, i, j, k, l, hasta))
          }

          for (m in vecindad(l)) {
            if (sonVecinos(m, hasta)) {
              return(c(desde, i, j, k, l, m, hasta))
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
}
```

ACLARACIÓN: Con vecindad me refiero en realidad a una ex-vecindad.
Por lo que, en este caso, B es vecino de A pero A no es vecino de B.

[image: Red ejemplo que en el código en github]

La idea de esta función es encontrar en una red, al menos una ruta si es que existe entre cualesquiera dos pares de nodos.

El código completo (no es largo) está en https://github.com/denk08n88/redes-IDO/blob/master/rutas.R

Agradezco su ayuda.

Comment: Hola japatronvi, bienvenido. ¿Podrías agregar un ejemplo mínimo de los datos que pasas a `ruta`. Unos aleatorios similares a los tuyos si no puedes hacerlos públicos. También de la función `sonVecinos()`. Me parece que lo que te serviría sería `while`, que sigue ejecutando el loop hasta que se cumple una condición, en este caso `sonVecinos`. De todos modos me cuesta pensar en el código en concreto sin los datos.

Comment: Hola @mpaladino , ya modifiqué la publicación. Estuve pensando también en un while, que vendía a sustituir los `if (sonVecinos(m, hasta))` pero aún no lo tengo muy claro. Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Tal como está actualmente tu función, te habrás dado cuenta que estas limitado a encontrar caminos de cierta longitud, más allá de esta longitud, por ejemplo, con este grafo:

```
desde <- c("C","A","A","B","D","E","C","F","F","H","F","H", "K", "L") 
hasta <- c("A","B","E","D","E","C","F","G","H","I","J","K", "L", "M")
```

`ruta("A", "M")` no muestra ningún camino, cuando en realidad si existe más de uno.

Ahora bien, para transformar este algoritmo en una función recursiva, hay que empezar por tener en cuenta los nodos visitados, para evitar eventuales caminos circulares. En tu algoritmo, esto no ocurre por que tienes una cantidad fija de iteraciones, pero seguramente verás que hay algunas soluciones que vuelven a pasar por el mismo nodo de partida, esto es un problema si vamos a usar recursividad por que podríamos generar un loop infinito. Tal vez el algoritmo más sencillo y en el que definitivamente se debería transformar tu rutina, es el conocido como [Depth first search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search). El funcionamiento es muy simple: Se comienza a navegar desde el nodo "desde" y se avanza lo más que se pueda hasta llegar al nodo "hasta", o bien hasta un final de camino o hasta un retorno a un nodo ya visitado, si no se encontró la solución, se retorna al nodo inmediatamente anterior y se repite el procedimiento. Este método nos asegura haber recorrido todas los nodos conectados del grafo, por lo que puede llegar a encontrar múltiples soluciones.

Tomé como ejemplo esta [implementación](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/depth-first-search-or-dfs-for-a-graph/) para llevarla a **R**:

```
all.paths <- function(red, nodes, desde, hasta, path=character(0)) {

    nodes[nodes$nodo==desde,]$visitado = T
    path <- c(path, desde)

    if (desde == hasta){
        print(path) 
    } else {
        vecinos <- as.character(red[red$Desde == desde, "Hasta"])
        for (nodo in vecinos) {
            if (!nodes[nodes$nodo == nodo, "visitado"]) {
                all.paths(red, nodes, nodo, hasta, path)
            }
        }
    }
    path <- path [!path %in% desde]
    nodes[nodes$nodo==desde,]$visitado = F
}
```

Esta es una implementación "cruda", hay muchas cosas mejorables y tendrías que "testerla" bien, pero al menos pareciera hacer lo correcto. Para usarla necesitamos generar un vector con todos los nodos y un atributo de `visitado`, algo así:

```
desde <- c("C","A","A","B","D","E","C","F","F","H","F","H", "K", "L") 
hasta <- c("A","B","E","D","E","C","F","G","H","I","J","K", "L", "M")
red <- data.frame(Desde = desde, Hasta = hasta)

# la lista de nodos con un atributo "visitado" necesario
nodos = data.frame(nodo = unique(c(as.character(red$Desde), as.character(red$Hasta))), 
                   visitado = F)

all.paths(red, nodos, "A", "C")
all.paths(red, nodos, "A", "M")
```

La salida:

```
> all.paths(red, nodos, "A", "C")
[1] "A" "B" "D" "E" "C"
[1] "A" "E" "C"
> all.paths(red, nodos, "A", "M")
 [1] "A" "B" "D" "E" "C" "F" "H" "K" "L" "M"
[1] "A" "E" "C" "F" "H" "K" "L" "M"
```

Podrás notar que el algoritmo puede encontrar varios caminos posibles y además que resolvió el camino más largo de "A" a "M".

**Importante:**

Más allá del interés educativo que conlleva implementar estos algoritmos, obviamente en **R** ya hay paquetes que resuelven este tipo de problemas, por ejemplo [igraphs](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/igraph) o [graph](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/graph) e incluso tenemos [tidygraph](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/tidygraph).